# Xcode 5 and iPhone 5S - Running app "crashes" device (sort of)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, urbanairship.com

I'm creating a new app. Very, very initial stages (i.e., it literally has no custom code yet). All I've done so far is a basic implementation of Urban Airship's libraries.

Sometimes (about 50% of the time?), when I push the app to my device, the following occurs:

1. App doesn't load on device
2. Xcode reports "failed to get task for process"
3. Device exhibits odd behavior.

"Odd behavior" includes:

1. Device wallpaper disappears and is replaced with an all black background.
2. Tapping on any icons gives them a pressed/shadowed look, but nothing happens.
3. Tapping on the icon again sets it back to its normal state. Again, nothing else.
4. Pressing home button does nothing.
5. Pressing lock button will lock device, but no attempt to unlock the device (home button or lock/unlock button) has no effect.
6. Attempting to use Siri gives the initial sound, but nothing further.

Hard rebooting the device gets it functional again. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to when this "bug" appears.

Has anyone else encountered this "bug"?

Comment: I've had similar issues. It at least seems like being sure to stop the run before running again can keep this from happening.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Any luck in finding the reason or a solution? It's getting on my nerve!